# Save CoreData to iCloud (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

I have already a CoreData, then now i want to save a data to iCloud.

In AppDelegate.swift

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
        var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator =
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator (managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

        var storeURL =
        self.applicationDocumentsDirectory
            .URLByAppendingPathComponent("DeviceCoreData.sqlite")

        var storeOptions =
        [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : "MyDevices"
            // NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption: @(true)
        ]

        //
        self.registerCoordinatorForStoreNotifications (coordinator)

        var error : NSError? = nil
        var store : NSPersistentStore! =
        coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType (NSSQLiteStoreType,
            configuration: nil,
            URL: storeURL,
            options: storeOptions,
            error: &error)

        if nil == store {
            // handle error
        }

        return coordinator
        }()

func registerCoordinatorForStoreNotifications (coordinator : NSPersistentStoreCoordinator) {
    let nc : NSNotificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter();

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoresWillChange:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification,
        object: coordinator)

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoresDidChange:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification,
        object: coordinator)

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoresWillRemove:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorWillRemoveStoreNotification,
        object: coordinator)

    nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoreChangedUbiquitousContent:",
        name: NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification,
        object: coordinator)
}
```

But when i build application, i got a error message

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Ơn_Giời.AppDelegate
>   handleStoresDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x17668770'

Someone can help me ? I stack here 3 days.

And

```
[NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : "MyDevices"]
```

This Key is correct or not ? My cloudkit named iCloud.MyDevices
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Writing a `handleStoresDidChange` function is certainly a good start, that's what the exception is telling you.

Comment: @pNre : hi. When i disable this line, the application is work (w/o error). But i can not save my coredata to icloud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

```
nc.addObserver(self, selector: "handleStoresDidChange:",
    name: NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresDidChangeNotification,
    object: coordinator)
```

says that when that notification is posted, a method named `handleStoresDidChange:` should be called, on the object `self` (apparently, the app delegate)

The error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Ơn_Giời.AppDelegate handleStoresDidChange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17668770'
```

says that `AppDelegate` does not have a method named `handleStoresDidChange:`.

This is why the app crashes: You have instructed the notification center to call a method that does not exist. If you tell the notification center it should call a method, that method **must** exist. You need to either create that method or tell the notification center to call some other method that does exist.

Comment: Thank you, i found the problems. Thanks again

Comment: @ZoomNguyễn don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @Tom Harrington you have explained the error very well. Very helpful. thanks